# update "quantity remaining" without refreshing site

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I have an HTML site with a page that uses PHP code which queries a MySQL database.  The table contains 3 columns (date, time, remaining). Based on the current date and time, I would like the HTML page to return and display the corresponding value from the "remaining" column.

The trick is I would like this value to update automatically (AJAX?) without the user having to refresh the page or click on a button.

The PHP I have so far works in that it displays the "remaining" value based on the date, but I haven't figured out how to query for both date and time, nor the auto-refreshing.

PHP Code I have figured out so far

*(note: `quantitytest_config.php` simply contains the hostname/username/password)*

```
    <?php

include 'quantitytest_config.php';

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

//select a database to work with
$selected = mysql_select_db("grace59_countdown",$dbhandle) 
  or die("Could not select countdown");

//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mysql_query("SELECT remaining FROM quantity WHERE salesdate=CURDATE()");
//fetch tha data from the database
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo "Quantity:".$row{'remaining'}."<br>";
}

//close the connection
mysql_close($dbhandle);
?>
```

Thanks in advance for your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to learn AJAX :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`jQuery.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/), it's a breeze, the following snippet will call your PHP script and update the remaining count every 10 seconds.

```
setInterval(function(){
    // Assumes the container has the id of count
    // and the php script is called remaining.php
    $("#count").load("remaining.php")
}, 10000);
```

Without jQuery, you'll have to do some reading, but it's not that hard

As far as any other questions you have embedded into the same question. You should not ask multiple questions as one. Each question should show what you've tried, expected/actual behavior, error messages. That's how your question can be useful to others, not just yourself, and that's at the heart of Stack Overflow. Currently your question is I don't know how to do it, and that's not a very good fit for SO.

Comment: thanks Juan!  I gave that a try and it works like a charm.  My apologies for the multiple questions, and not following your other suggestions.  I'll be sure to do that from now on.

Comment: @Zander No need to apologize, welcome to stack overflow, glad it worked.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, you should use AJAX.

Basically, from time to time, you'll keep calling a page and check if the new results (if they exist) and retrieve them to the user.

The page you'll be calling is a PHP file like the one you posted, that'll be returning the results for the AJAX call.

After the call, the results will be presented to the user.

Usually, in AJAX GET method is faster as it doesn't  involve proccessing POST fields, and, as you are only getting information, I would stick it.

Here is a basic syntax for what you are looking for. It kinda haves some complex but understandable names I guess.

```
<script>
setInterval(function(){check_new_stuff();}, 10000);

function check_new_stuff(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "url_with_your_php_code.php",
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {name_of_the_parameter_to_be_passed_in_get: value_of_the_parameter_to_be_passed_in_get},

    success: function(html){
             $("#div_to_have_its_html_replaced_with_the_result_from_php_code").html(html);
    },

    error: function(){
    },

    complete: function(){
    }
  });

  setTimeout(function(){check_new_stuff();}, 10000);
}
</script>
```

(you can [read more about this here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/))

About your question regarding the time, I've not seen a problem in it. You just need to add the field and pass a time value to it in the database query?

**(if you want current time? - trying to guess your column names as you don't maintain the table nomenclature the same all over your explanation)**

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT remaining FROM quantity WHERE salesdate=CURDATE() AND salestime=CURTIME()");
```

**(specific time, specified by yourself?)**

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT remaining FROM quantity WHERE salesdate=CURDATE() AND salestime='11:15:00'");
```

Comment: Thanks Ivo, and sorry for making you guess on the column names (which you did correctly!).  

So my table consists of 'salesdate', 'salestime' and 'remaining'. I'd like the query to match today's date and the last valid time in the table.  Unfortunately the first suggestion:     
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT remaining FROM quantity WHERE salesdate=CURDATE() AND salestime=CURTIME()")
will only provide a result if the current time is exactly the same as any value in the 'salestime' column, otherwise it returns nothing. Unfortunately, I can't find any solution in the MySQL documentation.

Comment: What do you mean a valid time? Some row that has its row filled? If so, try doing this: $result = mysql_query("SELECT remaining FROM quantity WHERE salesdate=CURDATE() AND salestime!='00:00:00'");

Comment: By valid time I mean: My table will be pre-filled with data. So let's say the table has 10 filled rows of dates, times and remaining and that these values could contain past and future dates/times. I want the query to return the 'remaining' value from only ONE row - from the row that most closely matches today's date and the current time, but not a future time.

Comment: figured it out...SORT and LIMIT will do the trick.  Just changed my query to:
 $result = mysql_query("
                SELECT remaining 
  FROM quantity_time 
  WHERE salesdate<=CURDATE() 
  AND salestime<=CURTIME() 
  ORDER BY salesdate DESC
  LIMIT 1 ");

Comment: I'm glad you got it! By the way, if by any means, my response helped you somehow getting closer to the result, please mark it as the correct answer. Thanks!